# Recyclerview recreating dynamic chips on scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-chips

I am creating a `RecyclerView` which has an item with dynamic chips. I am looping through an array to set the text of the chip, this works fine but when I scroll the `RecyclerView`, more chips gets created

```
class Adapter(activity: Activity): RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder>() {
    val mActivity = activity

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val itemView: View?
        itemView = parent.inflate(R.layout.item, false)
       return Holder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 7
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindView()
    }



    inner class Holder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        private val binding: ItemBinding = ItemBinding.bind(view)
        private val array: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(5)
        init {
           
        }

        fun bindView() {
            binding.textView.text = ""
            for (item in array){
                val mChip: Chip = mActivity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chip,null,false) as Chip
                mChip.text = item
                val paddingDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10f,
                    mActivity.resources.displayMetrics
                ).toInt()
                mChip.setPadding(paddingDp, 0, paddingDp, 0)
                mChip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { Toast.makeText(mActivity.applicationContext, absoluteAdapterPosition.toString()+ mChip.text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                binding.chips.addView(mChip)
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: View inflation should be in onCreateViewHolder method of RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: Can you post your adapter and class code?